# Compile only one target from a stack project with multiple targets in the cabal file

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I have a [similar setup like this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238729/producing-multiple-executables-from-single-project).
However I'm working with *stack* and not directoly with *cabal*:

```
stack.yaml
Test.cabal
src/FirstExe
src/SecondExe
```

The stack file is minimal

```
resolver: lts-8.17
packages:
- '.'
```

The file *Test.cabal* has 2 executables:

```
name:               Test
version:            0.1.0.0
build-type:         Simple
cabal-version:      >=1.8

executable FirstExe
  hs-source-dirs:   src
  main-is:          FirstExe.hs
  build-depends:    base >=4.8 && <4.10

executable SecondExe
  hs-source-dirs:   src
  main-is:          SecondExe.hs
  build-depends:    base >=4.8 && <4.10
```

The *src/FirstExe.hs* compiles successfully:

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "FirstExe compiles nicely"
```

The *src/SecondExe.hs* has an error:

```
main :: IO ()
main = "SecondExe gives compiler error"  -- putStrLn is missing ...
```

(Note: The goal of this error is to see, when stack builds the *SecondExe*.)

When I do a `stack ide targets` I get

```
Test:exe:FirstExe
Test:exe:SecondExe
```

Now I want to compile **only** the first target *FirstExe* without compiling the second and without changing
the *Test.cabal* file. In reallity I will switch between the 2 executables.

According to the [*Haskell Tool Stack* documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/v1.4.0/build_command/#target-syntax) it should
be possible

I tried two possibilies:

```
stack build  :FirstExe
stack build Test:exe:FirstExe
```

In both cases it compiles the second executable too!

```
Test-0.1.0.0: configure (exe)
Configuring Test-0.1.0.0...
Test-0.1.0.0: build (exe)
Preprocessing executable 'FirstExe' for Test-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'SecondExe' for Test-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src/SecondExe.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/SecondExe/SecondExe-tmp/Main.o )

/home/roland/Projekte/HaskellTutorials/Test/src/SecondExe.hs:2:8: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `[Char]'
    * In the expression: "SecondExe gives compiler error"
      In an equation for `main': main = "SecondExe gives compiler error"

--  While building package Test-0.1.0.0 using:
      /home/roland/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build exe:FirstExe exe:SecondExe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a known issue, related to deficiencies in Cabal, see https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1406

Comment: @mgsloan it looks like the latest stack should resolve this? can you provide that as an answer if so?

Comment: @sclv: Many thanks for the hint. What is _latest version_?  Is it what I get with `stack upgrade` (1.6.3 as of today 27. Feb 2018) or is it the current version from [https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack)?

Comment: From my reading of the above referenced ticket (which is where I got my info) this should be in 1.6.3

Comment: @sclv: I retested and unfortunately, I have to report _no success_. The problem is still here! I'm using: stack 1.6.3, lts-10.0, ghc 8.2.2, cabal-install 2.0.0.1 Cabal library 2.0.1.0. The above referenced issue 1406 points to [issue #3486 stack build copies unnecessary executables when asked to build just a single executable](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3486) and this is issue is still open.

Comment: The latest version of stack solves this, but only if you've built all executables at least once.  You can probably trick it by shimming in an empty file in the directory that it checks

Comment: @mgsloan: Many thanks for your kind hint! Yes, this way it works! It's a little bit tricky, but I'll get used to it...